# Insert in a table based on result of a select from another table

Tags: java, sql, liquibase

I have 2 Tables Named `Shop` and `Location`

- table `Shop` has a column `name`
- table `Location` has a column `description`

For every line of table shop, I want to insert a line in table Location that respect the following structure:

```
Location.description = Shop.name + "-Location"
```

So for every Shop, I want to insert a location with

```
description=Shop.name.concat("-Location")
```

Please how can I write one sql query to solve this problem.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `insert . . . select`. Presumably, you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO location(description)
    SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(s.name, '-Location')
    FORM shops s;
```

You can also use `||` for string concatenation in many databases:

```
INSERT INTO location(description)
    SELECT DISTINCT s.name || '-Location'
    FORM shops s;
```

Comment: I use what you proposed, but i got and SQL error  telling that function concat is not recognized. so i change the concatenation a do as follow:

   INSERT INTO location(description)
 SELECT s.name || '-Location'
 FROM shops s;

and it worked properly
thanks so much for your help

Comment: @BlaiseFeukouo . . . `concat()` is the ANSI standard function for concatenating strings, however most databases have their own methods.  When I answered the question, I don't think the question was tagged with a database.  `||` works in many databases.

Comment: ok. thanks @Gordon Linoff for your answer.
I'm currently using Postgresql as database. but, my application is supposed to work with any database, because I'm using JPA (eclipseLink). so the sql query I write in my liqubase changeset is supposed to not depend to the database used. please, do you think the solution I have adopted is the right one for the situation?